# Draw an elliptical frame in xaml

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

I need to show a numbers in circle kind of figure. that is feasible by me, but problem starts when there are 2 or 3 digit numbers. what is expected to happen is circle should become ellipse.How to make write ellipse in xaml. Can ellipse itself be shown as circle.how to set text in ellipse?

Comment: Do you mean an oval shape? That's 'ellipse'. Or do you mean one circle partially obscuring another temporarily? (which actually would be an 'eclipse').

Comment: Andrew Shepherd : please check

Answer (score 1):

I have used this TextBoxStyle in the past to give me some rounded corners, making some modifications to it as I did here might give you something that may work or give you some ideas. See if something like this works for you.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication24" x:Class="WpfApplication24.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="90,90,90,90">
                        <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
      <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle }" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Text="12345" />
</Grid>
```

[image]